# Powershell script pasting text neither into cmdexe nor powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

### Introduction

Recently, I came to the conclusion that typing something with :

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("XY")
```

takes a much longer time than using :

```
 Set-Clipboard -Value "XY"
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^V") (CTRL+V)
```

to copy and paste it, so I tried implementing it into my bigger script.

### The problem

I have a minor difficulty with it due to it not pasting the copied text into powershell.exe or cmd.exe.

Using the exact same script to paste a message in notepad works.

In my case, I'm trying to paste a command into cmd. Let's say the command is "echo $text" with $text = "HELLO"

```
    $text = "HELLO"
    
start cmd.exe
      
sleep -Milliseconds 300
     Set-Clipboard -Value "echo $text"
         
sleep -Milliseconds 300
     [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^V")
           
sleep -Milliseconds 300
      [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{Enter}")
```

It doesn't end up pasting "echo HELLO" like it should, but it sends "^V" in the command line,  but as I stated earlier, it does paste "echo HELLO" in notepad just fine which confused me a bit.

If you know the answer or a different approach to this issue, I'd appreciate it if you shared it with me!

Comment: Replace `^V` by `^v`, which works for me with cmd.exe, powershell.exe and pwsh.exe

Comment: @zett42 would you mind posting this as an answer so I can flag it?

Comment: While this may appear to be caused by a typo (`^V` vs `^v`), I believe this has value to future readers considering that if you press `Ctrl+Letter` for an unsupported shortcut, it will output the capital letter to the terminal. This is exemplified in PS 4 where `Ctrl+V`  does *not* paste by default, but instead prints a literal `^V` to the screen. The answer on this question however suggests that you must send the lowercase variant when sending keys to forms.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest You should post a version of your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole It's not really an answer adding any new information the current answer doesn't cover. I'm posting this on the question itself as it came up in the CV review queue with "Not reproducible or caused by a typo". Technically, I suppose it is a typo but it's a common misunderstanding that PowerShell itself contributes to.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I also came across it in the close votes review queue. I think your assessment is valid and adding the information as a formal answer would make this Q/A an overall better resource for "future readers". But it's entirely up to you, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments by @Zett42, this is corrected by using `^v` instead of `^V`.